# How to compile programs to enable LLDB debugging symbols?

Tags: ruby, lldb

On my MacBook at work, I'm trying to use LLDB to attach to a running Ruby process.

It's normally suggested that one compile Ruby with the debug flag -ggdb(3) to use GDB. But I can't find anything equivalent for LLDB. My Google-fu is failing me, so I thought I'd ask, since this seems like an obscure request.

Comment: I can't even remember what the `-ggdb` command line arg does for gcc.  I would strongly recommend against using it.  Use plain on `-g` and you will get all the information the debugger needs from the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that all that -ggdb does is produce debug information. The format for this debug information is most likely DWARF, which both GDB and LLDB understand

If that is the case, -ggdb is a misnomer and should be fixed. But, for your intents and purposes, you should be able to just compile with -ggdb and then attach with LLDB and things should be all right

Comment: I don't quite get the results I want when just using -ggdb. I might mark this question as answered and create a new question for the specific problem I'm getting.

Comment: The more details the better!